# Create a video banner with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video

I'm developing a bootstrap site for which I want a video banner at the top similar to what [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/) does. To do that, I'm using bootstrap's embed-responsive classes as shown in the code snippet below.

```
<div class="container-fluid" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <div class="row">
    <video autoplay muted loop class="embed-responsive-item" id="autovid" width="100%" >
        <source src="sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

That puts the video in my web page but now I want to stretch it across the entire screen. I thought container-fluid and setting the width to 100% would do that but its still only taking up part of the screen. It's also not responding when I shrink the window like its supposed to in Bootstrap. How do I stretch it across the entire screen and get it to be responsive to size changes?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary problem is how you are implementing the width of the video object. When you give it the class attribute of `embed-responsive-item` you are essentially overriding the width with whatever is in the style sheet, in this case the bootstrap default styles. In any case, you should really shape your web-page via an external style sheet.

You can do this by linking to it via the `<link>` tag, for example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Create a file named `style.css` and insert the following code.

```
video { width: 100%; }
```

Now understand that this will not always make the video fill the page. As you know your video tag is inside of a `<div>` tag. This will only make the video take up the full width of that container. If that container's full width is not the width of the webpage then it will obviously not take up the full width of the page.

I suggest you read more about nesting elements in html [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp), and the box model [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

Comment: Also note that this will make all <video> tags take up the full width of their containers.